# Video session timeout counter

Tags: mysql, angular, rxjs

I am trying to implement a video session timeout counter in Angular & MySQL DB where if both user are in the same session, they will see the same timeout counter showing in their video session. If one of the user disconnected and reconnect back, he/she will get the latest timeout counter. For example, they disconnected at minute 25:34. They have reconnected after 5 minutes exactly, and the counter that he/she will see is 20:34.

In this case I assume the timeout counter should be stored in the database.

I wonder if there is anyway to do it without storing the timeout in the database?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you should store video_end_timestamp in a database.
2. you get the timeout counter by video_end_timestamp - currenttimestamp